# CoreMotion deviceMotionUpdateInterval ignored

Tags: swift, ios9, core-motion

I was playing around with the deviceMotionUpdateInterval and I can't really see any change when I set it. The handler is getting called at maximum. Am I doing something wrong? Is that a bug?

```
var counter = 0

if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true)
{
    self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1
    let handler:CMAccelerometerHandler = {(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        counter++
        print(counter)
    }
    self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: handler)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the wrong property. The `deviceMotionUpdateInterval` is for device motion updates. That's not what you've asked for; you've asked for accelerometer updates. For accelerometer updates, you would want to set the `accelerometerUpdateInterval`.